# Get instance by exact M2M values

Tags: django, django-models

I have a conversation Thread model with a `members` M2M field to User.

What I need to do is to get the instance of Thread which has only specific members related, no more, no less.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do something like this:

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='threads')

>> user_threads = user.threads.filter(any_condition)
```

editing:

What you need looks something like this:

```
>> exact_users = [user1, user2, ...]
>> ts = Thread.objects.filter(members__in = exact_users)
```

Comment: But what filter should I use? If I use members__in=members then it returns all the threads that have ANY of the members in. I need to choose only those that have only that set of members.

Comment: You need to get all threads that match exactly a set of 'n' users ?

Comment: @Hvandracas If you have extra results, you could always combine the filter with an exclude clause.