# Django queryset to filter objects with identical manytomany field

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-queryset

I've got a model like this.

```
class Component(models.Model):
     options = models.ManyToManyField('prices.Option')
     period = models.IntegerField()
```

I need to select all components with same period and same options as one component **cmp**. This queryset doesn't work.

```
similar_components = Component.objects.filter(period=cmp.period, options=cmp.options)
```

I can't find a way to make a queryset baset on this manytomany field `options`.

Comment: Could you try this, similar_components = Component.objects.filter(period=cmp.period, options=[cmp.options])

Comment: @kamilyrb This will not work. I will correct my answer now

Comment: You can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13589692/7659834). There is answer of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

```
from django.db.models import Q

options = cmp.options.all()
filter_kwargs = (Q(options=option) for option in options)
similar_components = Component.objects.filter(period=cmp.period).filter(*filter_kwargs)
```

Comment: He wants to same options,this query returns components which contains cmp.options. But there are also extra options.